# Get size of excel cell in pixels

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I am trying to programatically (C++ but VBA explanations are OK) get the size of an excel cell in pixels. The excel application gui shows the size of the cell as:
Width: **8.28 (160 pixels)** Height: **24.6 (41 pixels)**, Font is Arial 20 pt.

Using an excel range I can get the:
ColumnWidth: **8.3**, RowHeight: **24.6**
Range Width: **96**, Range Height **24.6**

I tried using PointsToScreenPixelsX and PointsToScreenPixelsY for all of the above values but they returned values which didn't match up with what the excel gui said (**396** for row/cell height, **136** for column width and **224** for column width).

Any ideas?

Comment: Those funky values are probably measurements in TWIPs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip).  If you want to convert twips, to pixels, check out this Microsoft article:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion from points to pixels depends on your DPI setting. There are 72 points to an inch, so if you have 96 points that's 4/3 of an inch. If your DPI (in Display Properties) is 120 then that works out to 160 pixels.

In other words, `pixels = points * DPI / 72`.

However, this doesn't take zoom into account. `ActiveWindow.Zoom` in Excel is a percentage, so for instance 200 is twice normal size. Note that the UI still shows unzoomed pixels.

Answer (score 3):

The OP stated:

> The excel application gui shows the size of the cell as:
>
> Width: **8.28 (160 pixels)** Height: **24.6 (41 pixels)**, Font is Arial 20 pt.

First let me clarify: the **application gui** shows column widths and height in a decimal measurement and a pixel measurement, regardless of font size, screen size, zoom, etc. For any of these factors, if the Excel column width is 8.43, it will **always** be defined as 64 *pixels*. Second, I am a little confused, because my version of Excel (2010 currently) and every prior version I can remember had the standard column width of 8.43 equal 64 *pixels*; likewise, the standard row height of 15 equals 20 *pixels*, which does not seem to match the OP's example.

Having established that, one poster asked "Why?" One reason: if you're adjusting column widths or row heights, Excel allows that in **discrete units** that, unfortunately, they decided to name *pixels*. Maybe they related to pixels in some early version, but they seem just as random as the units used - 8.43 is what, inches, picas, ??? Not twips, that's for sure! Here, I'll call it a *decimal unit*.

Anyway, for all column widths over 1.00, that discrete *pixel* unit is 1/7th of a decimal unit. Bizarrely, column widths under 1.00 are divided into 12 units. Therefore, the discrete widths up to the 2.00 decimal unit are as follows:

```
0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 0.33, 0.42, 0.5, 0.58, 0.67, 0.75, 0.83, 0.92, 1.00, 
1.14, 1.29, 1.43, 1.57, 1.71, 1.86, 2.00
```

with 2.00 equaling 19 *pixels*. Yes, I'll pause while you shake your head in disbelief, but that's how they made it.

Fortunately, row heights appear to be more uniform, with 1 *pixel* equaling 0.75 decimal units; 10 *pixels* equaling 7.50; standard row height of 20 *pixels* equaling 15.00; and so on. Just in case you should ever need to convert between these randomly discrete units, here are a couple of VBA functions to do so:

```
Function ColumnWidthToPixels(ByVal ColWidth As Single) As Integer
    Select Case Round(ColWidth, 4)      ' Adjust for floating point errors
    Case Is < 0:
        ColumnWidthToPixels = ColumnWidthToPixels(ActiveSheet.StandardWidth)
    Case Is < 1:
        ColumnWidthToPixels = Round(ColWidth * 12, 0)
    Case Is <= 255:
        ColumnWidthToPixels = Round(12 + ((Int(ColWidth) - 1) * 7) _
            + Round((ColWidth - Int(ColWidth)) * 7, 0), 0)
    Case Else:
        ColumnWidthToPixels = ColumnWidthToPixels(ActiveSheet.StandardWidth)
    End Select
End Function

Function PixelsToColumnWidth(ByVal Pixels As Integer) As Single
    Select Case Pixels
    Case Is < 0:
        PixelsToColumnWidth = ActiveSheet.StandardWidth
    Case Is < 12:
        PixelsToColumnWidth = Round(Pixels / 12, 2)
    Case Is <= 1790:
        PixelsToColumnWidth = Round(1 + ((Pixels - 12) / 7), 2)
    Case Else:
        PixelsToColumnWidth = ActiveSheet.StandardWidth
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: 8.43 does not always equal 64 pixels.  The width in pixels is calculated as `8.43 * max(width(x) for x in '0123456789') + 5`.  The 8.43 is the number of character-width-units that fit in the cell.  The character-width-unit is the maximum width of the digit characters in the sheet's default font.  The additional 5 pixels is the cell padding.  For Calibri size 11, the character-width-unit is 7 pixels: `7*8.43 + 5 = 64`

Comment: What's your source for this mind-blowing information?  I can't seem to find anywhere else that discusses the ridiculous unit format that Excel uses.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

**Example**

This example determines the height and width (in pixels) of the selected cells in the active window and returns the values in the lWinWidth and lWinHeight variables.

```
With ActiveWindow
    lWinWidth = PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Selection.Width)
    lWinHeight = PointsToScreenPixelsY(.Selection.Height)
End With
```

Comment: Can you explain the strange values I got? (This is detailed in my post where I tried to use exactly what you are suggesting...)

Comment: +1. This works for me, but only approximately. :) If I start a new sheet and have the width written to cell A1, with the default Calibri 11 font, the cell shows 108 and Excel's UI shows me 109. If I increase the font size to 20, the cell shows me 119 and the UI shows me 124. I think this is getting into font character padding and proportional font stuff at this point...